# Number in the beginning vs. number in the end

Tags: cursor-motions

Yes, I know that `d2e` and `2de` are two different commands and therefore works slightly different, though it's not visible to the eyes.

Let's call them "number-in-the-middle" (nim) and "number-in-the-beginning" (nib). As I know, some commands doesn't work with nim syntax, but successfully works with nib one. So, is it a good idea (for newbies) to get rid of nim syntax and stick to nib, to have consistent behavior across all commands? And are there any commands that doesn't support nib syntax?

Comment: wait, how are `d2e` and `2de` different?

Comment: @Mass Here are some links: [first](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32010466), [second](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/44ow5v/is_there_a_difference_between_putting_a_number/) and [third](https://books.google.com/books?id=LA9QDwAAQBAJ) -- the pages in this book aren't numbered, so use a search phrase: "both d2w and 2dw will work".

Comment: The second link there seems to explain the difference. You should stick with nib, since it is always supported.

Comment: all of these links confirm that they are the same.  I would go further and say there is absolutely no difference between the two, certainly not from the point of view of vim's source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as built-in operators and motions go, they are completely identical.  There is some semantic value; "delete to 2 ends of words" vs "twice, delete to end of word," but from vim's perspective there is only a single count for the operator+motion.  You can provide both if you wish:

- `2d2e` means delete 4 to end.  The rule is that vim multiplies each given number to produce the count (which is 4).

In fact, you can use even more with registers:

- `2"ade` `2de`, but place in register `a`
- `"a2de` identical to above
- `"ad2e` identical to above
- `2"a2d2e`, delete to 8 ends of words, placing in register `a`.

Similarly, with puts from a register, you can specify multiple counts:

- `2"a2p` paste four times from reigster `p`.
- `2"a2"a2"a2"ap` paste 16 times from register `p`.

Some commands, despite not being operators or motions do support "middle" count.  The primary example is the `<c-w>` family of window commands.  `2<c-w>2w` means go to window 4.

There are some caveats though:

- some operators are multiple characters, like `gu`.  You can write `2gue` or `gu2e`, but not `g2ue`, since the operator is `gu` as a unit.
- some motions and text objects are multiple characters.  `d2iw` is fine, but `di2w` is meaningless.  `d2gj` is good, but `dg2j` is not.
- custom maps can break.  Let's say you make the map

  ```
  onoremap <space> 2w
  ```

  Then `2d<space>` works exactly as you expect: it deletes four words.  However, `d2<space>` means `d22w`!

Comment: I believe there exists a slight variation in handling the dot command `.` but I’d be willing to be proven wrong

Comment: As I understand you agree that nib is better for newbies?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I think if there is such a variation, that needs to be proven, not the opposite.  Otherwise, there is no reason to suspect they are different.  I have never seen a difference, but I'd also be willing to be proven wrong...

johnc.j., not sure who you were asking but my answer indented to say that neither was better for people new to vim.

Comment: Experimentation indeed proved me wrong. What I had remembered reading in Practical Vim was the caveat that often counting is hard, and hitting `.` after, e.g., `de`, is much easier.